# Getting date from mongodb java to jsp shows null

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

The setter and getters are Date type
This is my code for the connection:

```
    public void connectToDb() {
        try {
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
            DB db = mongoClient.getDB("bookingSystem");
            bookingsCol = db.getCollection("bookings");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
         }
      }
```

The code for getting the values in mongo which is:

---

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5820145df23fc5ccffd52155"),
    "userID" : "1B",
    "bookings" : [
                    {
                    "startDateTime" : ISODate("2017-08-22T08:00:00Z")
                    }
                  ]
```

---

```
    public Booking getBooking(int bookingID, String userID) {
        connectToDb();
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("bookings.bookingID", bookingID);
        DBCursor cursor = bookingsCol.find(query);
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject theObj = cursor.next();

        BasicDBList bookingsList = (BasicDBList) theObj.get("bookings");
        for (int i = 0; i < bookingsList.size(); i++) {
            BasicDBObject bookingObj = (BasicDBObject) bookingsList.get(i);
            Date startDateTime = bookingObj.getDate("startDateTime");
            booking.setStartDateTime(startDateTime);
        }
    }
    return booking;
   }
```

when i return the value, receiving the format : Fri Sep 22 12:00:00 MUT 2017 which is good, as it matches my input but when i do booking.getStartDateTime() from jsp. for date it is null, but the size is 1. The

In the jsp now the the getListOfBooking() is a function in my booking class which returns an Array of Objects that is why i did the .size() to know if it has values. I tried doing it with a string and it works however with the date it shows error.

```
        <%
        out.println(bookings.getListOfBooking().get(0).getStartDateTime());
        out.println(bookings.getListOfBooking().size());
        %>
```

Comment: Knowing what the error is would be helpful...

Comment: When i want to print the value it shows null. Otherwise there is no error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're not accessing the correct document layer. When you do this, `BasicDBObject bookingObj = (BasicDBObject) bookingsList.get(i);`, you're getting the topmost layer of your document while your `startDateTime` resides in next layer (embedded document)

You should be doing this instead :

```
BasicDBList bookingsList = (BasicDBList) theObj.get("bookings");
    for (int i = 0; i < bookingsList.size(); i++) {
        //this one gets the first document
        BasicDBObject bookingObj = (BasicDBObject) bookingsList.get(i);
        //this one gets 'bookings' embedded document, which is also a list
        List<BasicDBObject> embeddedBookingObjList = (List<BasicDBObject>) bookingObj.get("bookings");
        Date startDateTime = embeddedBookingObjList.get(0).getDate("startDateTime");
        booking.setStartDateTime(startDateTime);
    }
```

I didn't handle `List` exceptions, but I'm sure you can see what error might happen. By the way, try using `Document` instead, read the DBObject part : http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/bson/documents/